Charging for cashflow mismatch in Liability Driven investment
I am doing a course on LDI and the following question came up:
We are given a liability schedule. The liability is backed by a bond paying fixed coupons. The bond and the liability have the same PV and duration, but there is a big degree of mismatch.
I am asked to determine the cost of the cashflow mismatch and express it as a haircut to the bond yield. The Bond Yield is 5.06%.
I am also asked to assume that I can reinvest excess cash at 5.06%, but any borrowing will be at a rate of 6%.  I added the asset and liability cashflows below.
Don't know how to approach the question, any help is much appreciated!


Im just making this up as I go along, but given the two rates you have specified, financing at 6% and investing at 5.06% I would simply evaluate your net cashflows on an on going basis at see what you end up with.
Your final cash balance multiplied by your final DF is the cost (or gain) of your strategy. If you had no mismatches your net cash balance would always be zero and there would be nothing to finance or invest. I get a cost of this as -0.679.
I would consider it trivial to reverse engineer my formulas below.


this is very helpful. Easy to understand rationale and follow through the calcs. Much appreciated!
